# How to set chrome options.setPageLoadStrategy in serenity-cucumber framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I've been facing an issue with the Chrome browser timeout with the log as below,

[1538530975.003][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 57.998
[1538530975.008][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.005

Upon some research found a solution (ref: https://www.skptricks.com/2018/08/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-selenium.html) to set the chrome options as,

***ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);***

Not sure as to how do I configure the same in Serenity properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some tips for setting up the chrome on authors' blog https://johnfergusonsmart.com/configuring-chromedriver-easily-with-serenity-bdd/ I think there is also possibility to provide options in @Managed(options = "xxx") annotation, but I haven't tried this personally.

Comment: this article speaks about basics of chrome options, it doesn't discuss about the setpageloadstrategy and i've tried some hacks based on this article, none came to my rescue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's chrome.capabilities.pageLoadStrategy=none